# the result lambda expression excuted "ToList()" method is diffrent than bofore

Tags: .net, reflection, lambda

It's my code:

Project 1:

```
public interface IComponent{}

public class ComponentTest:IComponent{}

public class Bootstraper
{
   public virtual IEnumerable<IComponent> GetComponents()
   {
       return Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "*.dll")
       .Select(Assembly.LoadFile).SelectMany(m => m.GetTypes()).Select(m => m.GetTypeInfo())
       .Where(m => !m.IsAbstract && !m.IsInterface 
                   && typeof(IComponent).IsAssignableFrom(m)).ToList()
       .Select(Activator.CreateInstance).Cast<IPlatformComponent>();
   }
}
```

Project UnitTest:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetComponenentsIsSuccess()
{
    Bootstraper testObj=new Bootstraper();

    IEnumerable<IComponent> ienumerable = testObj.GetComponents();
    Assert.IsTrue(ienumerable.Any(m=>m.GetType()==typeof(ComponenentTest)));
}
```

it can't find `ComponenetTest` when excuting the unit test.

I have two questions:

1.on VS Debugger View,the code 
`Where(m=>!m.IsAbstract&&!m.IsInterface&&typeof(IComponent).IsAssignableFrom(m))`
can got Type `ComponenentTest`,But the type was dispeared when `ToList()` method excuted.

2.the type `ComponentTest` is dispear when code is `typeof(IComoponent)` ,but I use `typeof(object)` instead,after excuted 'ToList()',`ComponentTest` is still in collection

Comment: the runtime is .net core 2.0

Answer (score 0):

for Tolist() add namespace 
using System.Linq;

Comment: the namespace was added